# How to perform a sorted search in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input string which looks like this:

```
ms = 'hello stack overflow friends'
```

And a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
      string  priority  value
0         hi         1      2
1  astronaut        10      3
2   overflow         3     -1
3     varfoo         4      1
4      hello         2      0
```

Then I'm trying to do the following simple algorithm:

1. Sort ascending the pandas dataframe by `df['priority']` column.
2. Check if the `ms` string variable contains the `df['string']` word.
3. If so, return its `df['value']`.

Therefore, this is my approach to do so:

```
import pandas as pd

ms = 'hello stack overflow friends'

df = pd.DataFrame({'string': ['hi', 'astronaut', 'overflow', 'varfoo', 'hello'],
                   'priority': [1, 10, 3, 4, 2],
                   'value': [2, 3, -1, 1, 0]})

final_val = None

for _, row in df.sort_values('priority').iterrows():
    # just printing the current row for debug purposes
    print (row['string'], row['priority'], row['value'])

    if ms.find(row['string']) > -1:
        final_val = row['value']
        break

print()
print("The final value for '", ms, "' is ", final_val)
```

Which returns the following:

```
hi 1 2
hello 2 0

The final value for ' hello stack overflow friends ' is  0
```

This code works ok, but the thing is that my df has like 20K rows, and I need to perform this kind of search more than 1K times.

This dramatically decreases the performance of my process. So is there a better (or simpler) approach than mine using pure pandas and avoiding unnecessary loops?

Comment: For starters, `ms.find(row['string'])` is a very slow operation. Split `ms` into words, convert the list into a set (make sure to do this _once_, not in the loop!), and use the `in` operator: `ms_set=set(ms.split())` outside of the loop, `if row['string'] in ms_set` in the loop.

Comment: @harvpan NLTK is totally useless for this problem.

Comment: How does `hi` get `1, 2`? `hi` is not in `ms`...

Comment: @DYZ, I thought NLTK would deal with text data easily. I have minimal experience with nltk though. You might be right.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @josh I just printed the current row content, and string `hi` has a priority of  `1` and a value of `2`. But as it is not contained in the `ms` string variable, we loop to read the next row `hello`. @harvpan I've already given an input/output example, what do I need to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that you can apply to your dataframe rather than using `iterrows`

```
match_set = set(ms.split())
def check_matches(row):
    return row['value'] if row['string'] in match_set else None

df['matched'] = df.apply(check_matches, axis=1)
```

Which gives you:

```
   priority     string  value  matched
0         1         hi      2      NaN
1        10  astronaut      3      NaN
2         3   overflow     -1     -1.0
3         4     varfoo      1      NaN
4         2      hello      0      0.0
```

Then you can sort the values and take the first non `NaN` value from `df.matched` to get what you called `final_value`.

```
df.sort_values('priority').matched.dropna().iloc[0]
0.0
```

---

Alternatively, you could sort and convert the df into a list of tuples:

```
l = df.sort_values('priority').apply(lambda r: (r['string'], r['value']), axis=1).tolist()
```

Giving:

```
l
[('hi', 2), ('hello', 0), ('overflow', -1), ('varfoo', 1), ('astronaut', 3)]
```

And write a function that stops when it hits the first match:

```
def check_matches(l):
    for (k, v) in l:
        if k in match_set:
            return v
check_matches(l)
0
```

Comment: Move `ms.split()` outside of the function; otherwise, it will be executed for each row; convert the result to a set because a set has a better lookup time.

Comment: Cheers! The problem of this approach is that this approach loops every single row of the dataframe even though it find a match in the second one... :(

Comment: If you don't want to loop through every row of the dataframe then you probably shouldn't be using a dataframe. I added a way to convert the data structure to get the same answer without looping through all the values, though I'm not sure which would be faster.